# Upload images inside nested serializers in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

How can i upload images when user is trying to create announcement. I need to upload images to my computer and assign them to the announcement that he is trying to create.

Models.py

```
class Announcement(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, blank=True)

def nameFile(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['images', str(instance.name), filename])


class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=nameFile, blank=True, null=True)
```

Views.py

```
class AnnouncementCreate(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = models.Announcement.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnnouncementSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)

class PhotoViewSet(ListAPIView):

    queryset = models.Photo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file = request.data.get('image')
        image = models.Photo.objects.create(image=file)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': "Uploaded"}), status=200)
```

Serializers.py

```
class AnnouncementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parameters = ParameterSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    photo = PhotoSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Announcement
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'address', 'date',
                  'price', 'description', 'author', 'parameters', 'photo']

class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('name', 'image')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CreateModelMixin` of the `CreateAPIView` calls the serializer listed. Therefore, you need to serialize and validate the image inside the `AnnouncementSerializer` using the `PhotoSerializer`. This can be done by overriding the `create` method of the `AnnouncementSerializer`:

```
class AnnouncementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parameters = ParameterSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    photo = PhotoSerializer(
                many=True, 
                required=False, 
                read_only=True) # Set read_only to True

    class Meta:
        model = Announcement
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'address', 'date',
                  'price', 'description', 'author', 'parameters', 'photo']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Serializes an image if it has been uploaded, then passes the image
        back to the validated_data to finish creating the Announcement.
        """
        image_data = self.context['request'].FILES
        if image_data:
            serializer = PhotoSerializer(data=image_data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            image = serializer.save()
            validated_data['image'] = image
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

That should be all you have to do.